# SOAP - connection refused

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I can't connect to a SOAP service

```
new SoapClient('https://stest.bankconnect.dk/2017/02/02/services/CorporateService?wsdl');
```

## error

> SoapClient::SoapClient(http://stest.bankconnect.dk/2017/02/02/services/CorporateService?xsd=xsd/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd):
>   failed to open stream: Connection refused
>   /var/www/dyntest.dk/php/class/Bankconnect.php(7)

When requesting the URL in the browser.. No problem.. I get the XML document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can browse the wsdl but the link to the xml is not working :

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="http://stest.bankconnect.dk/2017/02/02/services/CorporateService?xsd=xsd/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
```

its either wrong, not working, or most likely to be secured with a firewall or something else that prevents the connection.

Comment: The PHP soap client is strictly working with web standards. Even if the xsd file is hosted at w3c, it refuses to load, because the xmldsig definition got a loading delay. The W3C recommends to store these definitions locally. So just download the xsd from the W3C and store it locally and edit the link in the wsdl or contact the provider, that his wsdl is wrong.